# Can a component be added/registered after run time?

Tags: c#, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I would like to be able to do the following and am not sure if it is possible...

I would like to have a WASM Blazor application that can have components added after the application is compiled and running. For example, if I created a simple application that displays photos and give the user the ability to change the style by choosing a different component. Please ignore the fact that there may be better ways to "style", this is a simple example to illustrate my goal. Maybe these "style" components are listed and available for download but are NOT preloaded. I would like the user to be able to choose a different style and then, and only then, download the dll for the component from a remote repository and load that component into the running application so that it is available to render. I have looked into DynamicComponent and that shows some promise. But it seems as though most of the information I can find about this has the need to declare those types up front before compilation.

Does anyone know if what I am attempting is possible? Am I on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: If your objective is to speed up the WASM download time then don't bother. Blazor downloads many more files than required. So even if this was possible, the perf gains would be unpredictable.

Comment: I don't care if it takes 10 minutes to load a new component. It's not about efficiency, it's about capability. I am trying to find out if it is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold off on loading assemblies until they are required using Lazy Loading, give this a read:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-6.0